# DB connection string between two servers by Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, windows, domaincontroller

I have two servers, let's say they are APPSVR (ASP.NET) and DBSVR (SQL Server). Currently, the application running smoothly with database connection using SQL Server authentication with `User Id` and `Password`.

In the future, it must be changed with Windows Authentication `Integrated Security=True`. I have tried to change this but can't worked (DB connection failure).

We have domain controller also and both server in the same domain. I am not sure which one that must be configured in our environment (Domain/SQL Server/IIS Manager). What's the right procedure to do this?

Comment: Both. App pool must run under registered in domain account and this account must have proper permissions in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

1. Is your asp.net application already running with domain user authentication?
2. Do you need per user login for SQL server because you set up the
       access right on domain user rather than create your own access right
       system on your asp.net application?

Why i am asking you this? Because You need to consider the differences between web application and desktop application. In web application, the web server contact the sql server not the user pc.

So this complicate the setup if you want the web server to use the windows authentication to login to sql server then you need to set up the web server to somehow masquerade as the domain users. You also need to consider the scenario if user are accessing the web application from the internet.

I suggest using strong application only password for sql server connection using local user rather than domain Users. For access right you can simply create a new table to store domain user login id and their access right. This set up still allow login to web application using the domain Users but the database connection is not. The Advantage is you can minimize the access to simply few or even one user application only user you need to maintain in sql server rather than every domain Users that need to be registered on sql server if you use windows authentication.

If you still need the Windows Authentication set up than you can see [the info here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsz5788z.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

We recently had to change over to using Windows Auth instead of a SQL Account to access the DB from our ASP site.  The trick is to have the application pool start up with the same domain account you use to access the SQL Server and then you can just change your connection string to use Integrated Security.

The process is shown here:
https://thycotic.force.com/support/s/article/Using-Windows-Authentication-to-access-SQL-Server-Secret-Server